# Qt QSerialPort Read Write

Tags: c++, qt, buffer, qtserialport

I have issue with reading and writing from/to QSerialPort. I read what I have written. Here is some example code that proves that. Maybe I need to write and read from different channels. Code's provided below thx in advance. Provided log of the program with image.

Log of the program here

[image]

### MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QSerialPort *serialPort;
    QTimer* sendTimer;
    QByteArray receiveDataBuffer;

private slots:
    void onReadyRead();
    void onSendDataTimeout();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### MainWindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      serialPort(new QSerialPort),
      sendTimer(new QTimer)
{
    sendTimer->setInterval(1000);
    serialPort->setPortName("COM5");
    serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::Parity::NoParity);
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::DataBits::Data8);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::StopBits::TwoStop);
    serialPort->open(QSerialPort::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);

    connect(serialPort,&QSerialPort::readyRead,this,&MainWindow::onReadyRead);
    connect(sendTimer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&MainWindow::onSendDataTimeout);
    sendTimer->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::onReadyRead()
{
    receiveDataBuffer.append(serialPort->readAll());
    if (receiveDataBuffer.contains('^') && receiveDataBuffer.contains('$') && receiveDataBuffer.lastIndexOf('$') < receiveDataBuffer.lastIndexOf('^')) {
        QByteArray extractedByteArray;

        for(int i = receiveDataBuffer.lastIndexOf("$") ; i < receiveDataBuffer.lastIndexOf("^") + 1 ; i++){
            extractedByteArray.append(receiveDataBuffer[i]);
        }
        qDebug()<<"Received:"<<extractedByteArray<<endl;
        receiveDataBuffer.clear();
    }}

void MainWindow::onSendDataTimeout()
{
    qint64 result = serialPort->write("$10,0,123,123^");
    bool flush = serialPort->flush();
    result != -1 && flush ? qDebug()<<"Data sent"<<endl:qDebug()<<"Failed to send data"<<endl;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is your client in echo-mode or have you connected RX and TX?

Comment: I have connected RX and TX @user6556709

Comment: @user6556709 Also I have tried to write data with another software, and it worked just fine, didn't receive back what I have written. Am I doing something wrong with serialPort?

Comment: You most probably don't need to call flush but that should make no difference. By connected I mean have you connected RX with TX? (which would result in an echo.). QSerialPort itself doesn't support echo mode by itself (you have no flag to activate or deactive it) but you can set the echo mode in your operating system. Maybe it is set there.

Comment: No rx is not connected to tx) , I am using Windows 10, where the echo mode setting can be?? @user6556709

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to connect the different signals that are emitted when you read/write that from your port.

For instance to check that the data has been sent properly, according to the documentation you can use the signal [`QIODevice::bytesWritten`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten):

> The signal is emitted every time a payload of data has been written to the device's current write channel. The bytes argument is set to the number of bytes that were written in this payload.

```
connect(serialPort,&QSerialPort::bytesWritte, this, [](const qint64 bytes) {
    qDebug() << "Sent data: " << bytes << " bytes.";
});
```

To read the data, as you already did, you need to check the [`QIODevice::readyRead`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead)  signal:

> This signal is emitted once every time new data is available for reading from the device's current read channel. It will only be emitted again once new data is available, such as when a new payload of network data has arrived on your network socket, or when a new block of data has been appended to your device.

Regarding the problem you described, the first step to do is to ensure that your decive has not been configured to work in echo-mode. To turn it off, you will need to check your device interface.

If this is not the problem, check the available ports by using [`QSerialPort::availablePorts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html#availablePorts) and ensure that you are connecting to the right one. For example, to connect to the first port, you can do something like this and check that the configuration is compatible with your device:

```
auto serialInfo = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
serialPort->setPort(serialInfo[0]) 
auto ret = serialPort.open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite)
        && serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud38400)
        && serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8)
        && serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop)
        && serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
qDebug() << "Port has been configured properly?: " << ret;
```

If the problem persist, you can get the native handler and modify its properties by calling [`QSerailPort::handle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#handle).

> If the platform is supported and the serial port is open, returns the native serial port handle; otherwise returns -1.

The last option, it does not work in all platforms. Worse scenario, take a look into the official docs of [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). It provides a low-level interface that allows you to enable/disable the echo mode.

```
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(file, &options);
cfmakeraw(&options);
options.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE); // Add or disable the flags
tcsetattr(file, TCSANOW, &options);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. You gave me good idea of implementing some features, but I found out the problem was in another foolish thing. The other device was connected to serial port with "OneStop" stop bits, while I was connected with "TwoStop", I corrected it and the echoes have stopped. @mohabouje

Comment: Great! Did Qt return false when you set that property? @HrantNurijanyan

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::StopBits::TwoStop);
```

The other device was connected to serial port with `QSerialPort::StopBits::OneStop`.
So changing the stop bits `serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::StopBits::OneStop);`
solved the problem and there were no echoes anymore.Thx.